# Expresso Store ‘State’ Dropdown showing NO States

Tags: expresso-store

I must have done somethings but I am not sure what I did. No States show up in the dropdown. This is checkout2.html. Its just an empty select Form. I set the default in the admin to County: United States and State:California.

As I cycle through the checkout process, I get to /store/checkout2 and the form is there but State has no states in the dropdown. Also the default Country is Afghanistan. (odd because it set to United States.

It was working before but not, it stopped. Its on a testing server right now because I am rebuilding it. I reinstall ’store’ and made sure I am using 2.5.1.

I am baffled. Here is the link for the 'example store' I set up. It exhibits the same behavior no Sates in the dropdown.

Thanks ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to empty your cart between template and Store admin changes for it to be seen on the front-end of the site, this has to do with Store caching. I added a product to the cart and went to the checkout page and I am seeing the US and California as items in the dropdown.